# Best way to validate /etc/hosts from third party providers to avoid ads?

Tags: network

A lot of people use a huge `/etc/hosts` file to simply redirect ads and scam sites to 127.0.0.1. The interesting part about this approach is that you can have the same hosts on your tablet, your android phone, your mac, your linux box, etc, and all applications in your machine are subject to the /etc/hosts, so you don't need to configure browsers, proxies...

An example of a HUGE hosts file is from this [french website](http://rlwpx.free.fr/WPFF/hosts.htm).

I would like to create some scripts and use these hosts files in an automated manner, but I was afraid of some security issues: imagine that someone hacked the server from where I get the hosts file, and now is pointing gmail.com to a scam site for example.

So, I thought of just doing a simple validation: each line of the hosts file **must** begin with 127.0.0.1 or with a comment (`#`).

Is this a valid precaution measure? Do you see any problems with this approach?

Comment: I don't see an issue with those validation rules. It will prevent a hacker from redirecting users to malicious sites. However there may be a better method of securing your hosts file.

Comment: I'm planning to create a script that downloads hosts from various sources, removes duplicates, and does a simple validation of the 127.0.0.1 to avoid "man in the middle" attacks. This is going to be my hosts file: always dynamic from those sources. It may have a "manual" hosts file that I concatenate as well, but  only if needed, in the future. Do you see other security problems I may face when downloading hosts from other people beyond the "127.0.0.1 at the beginning of the line" check?

Comment: If a hacker was to compromise the hosts file, they could direct traffic for any hostname to the loopback address.

Comment: @Hammo Or worse, their own box. If they can get a DNS lookup on `your-bank.web` to point to their server, they can serve you with a phishing page.

Comment: I would like to point out.  The script the author want's to create already exists in the form of a well known application.  The name just escapes me for the moment.

Comment: @Ramhound There's a java app called "MergeHosts.jar" http://mathdotrandom.blogspot.com.br/2010/12/block-ads-on-pc-android-with-uber-hosts.html that merges hosts files, but doesn't do the whole process I was thinking of (downloading from a list and such).

Comment: @Hammo and Polynomial, could you explain (or provide some links) to this future scenario you both were thining of? Even in my situation, downloading a hosts file and checking if all lines start with 127.0.0.1? I couldn't understand how this attack would work...

Comment: I dont want to protect my hosts file when already in my device. I'm not looking for a way to protect the hosts after I moved it to /etc: after I downloaded them from these 3rd part sources, and run my "127.0.0.1" validation, I will suppose it's safe. That why I'm asking if my validation idea is missing something. In my android box I'm going to send it using adb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also want to allow for blank lines. But, "starts with #, 127., blank-line" should be sufficient if trying to validate 3rd party lists for inclusion in yours. Though this wouldn't stop malicious denial of service. For example, if you started performing this as a service, but then somebody placed your own domain name in the list with a 127.0.0.1.

Also,

A loopback address is not always 127.0.0.1 . I've seen some of these custom hosts files also use 127.0.0.2 or other 127.0.0.* addresses. [RFC 3330](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3330) defines loopback as any 127.0.0.0/8 address.

Also, this may not directly apply, but IPv6 localhost values such as 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 or ::1 are also valid.

Redirecting a site such a gmail would already be somewhat mitigated by the use of SSL certificates along with HTTP Strict Transport Security which tells a browser to only use SSL to connect to a site.